# How to use julia's HTTP.Websockets with a path and query string URL?

Tags: http, websocket, julia

Say I want my client to connect to the websocket `url = "ws://api.mysite.com/v1/user-stream?id=1"`.  How do I use HTTP.WebSockets server to handle this sort of url and parse path and query parameters?

```
Websockets.listen(...) do ws

                uri = ws.url # doesnt work
                path = uri.path
                query_params = queryparams(uri)
```

Update:

I figured out the query params but the path isn't returning anything.

```
path = ws.request.url.path
query_params = HTTP.queryparams(ws.request)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this a bug that has been fixed but not merged.

https://github.com/JuliaWeb/HTTP.jl/issues/1041

This will work:

```
path = ws.request.url.path
query_params = HTTP.queryparams(ws.request)
```